# Uncaught Typeerror,Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been doing some coding for class and I ran into a problem whilst coding for a traffic light system. Here is my code, the error is apparently around 21 and 22 and is an 'Uncaught Typeerror'. Could you please show me a few tips?

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        var trafficlights [ "red.png", "orange.png", "green.png"];
        var index = 0;

        function traffic() { // this part is tricky
            index = index + 1;
            if (index == index.length) 
                index = 0;

            var image = document.getElementById('light')[0];
            image.src = trafficlights[index].value = data;
        }
    </script>

    <img id="light" src="red.png" style="width:250px;height:250px;">
    <button type="button" onclick= "traffic()">click to change lights</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a typo; you're missing an `=` on this line: `var trafficlights = [ "red.png", "orange.png", "green.png"];` Also, research the [Modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) to save your `trafficlights.length` check.

Comment: Why do you do `index == index.length`? Accessing the non-existing `length` property of an integer will always return `undefined`

Comment: ok thanks for the help

Comment: Couple things to point out: There's no equal sign between `var trafficlights` and the array definition at the top. Also, `image.src=trafficlights     [index].value=data;` doesn't make sense. Get rid of `.value=data` at the end. Also, `index.length` doesn't make sense, you're testing teh upper boundary of the `trafficlights` array, so change it to that. Hopefully that will get you started in the right direction **without doing the homework for you. :D**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few syntax errors here:

```
var trafficlights [ "red.png", "orange.png", "green.png"];
```

Should be

```
var trafficlights = ["red.png", "orange.png", "green.png"];
                 ^^^
```

And here:

```
if (index == index.length)
```

There isn't a `length` defined onto a number, and also it wouldn't really make sense to compare a number to its "length", but I think you meant to do this:

```
if (index == trafficlights.length)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also here:

```
var image = document.getElementById('light')[0];
```

`document.getElementById` returns a single element; not an array. So it should look like:

```
var image = document.getElementById('light');
```

And lastly here:

```
image.src = trafficlights[index].value = data;
```

What is `data`? I don't think you need it, and when you refer to an array value you just call the element like so:

```
image.src = trafficlights[index];
```

Comment: thank you so much! its working now and u r all geniuses

Comment: @samfinlay Glad I could help!